# Google Map icon image on android

Tags: android, image, google-maps, android-intent

Im developing an aplication which shows the google map and some markers created by users.

This markers are populated by a external db, and conects via webservice.

Im putting an image from url in MarkerOptions() .icon from this DB. This imagem show correctly from all markers. But i have an intent too on setOnInfoWindowClickListener, and if i show this icon image, the intent doesnt work. If i remove the cod from icon image, the intent work correctly.

Can someone help me?

Codes

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    dao = new LocalizacoesDAO(context);
    ArrayList<Localizacoes> lista = dao.buscarLocalizacoes();
    if (lista.size() > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(""+lista.get(i).getImagem()+"");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bmpok = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 30, 30, false);

            googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(lista.get(i).getNome() + " " + lista.get(i).getDescricao())
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(lista.get(i).getId()))
                        .position(lista.get(i).getLatLng())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmpok)));

            }
        }
    }

 googlemap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,infoActivity.class);
            String title = marker.getTitle().toString();
            String snippet = marker.getSnippet();

            intent.putExtra("nome", title);
            intent.putExtra("id", snippet);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
}
```

ERROR

```
04-13 18:28:07.624    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:508)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:270)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:85)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.flush(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:49)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:188)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
04-13 18:28:07.634    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.partytime.myapplication.LocalizacoesDAO.buscarIdLocalizacoes(LocalizacoesDAO.java:191)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.partytime.myapplication.infoActivity.onCreate(infoActivity.java:36)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 18:28:07.644    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 18:28:07.654    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
04-13 18:28:07.654    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 18:28:07.654    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 18:28:07.654    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
04-13 18:28:07.654    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
04-13 18:28:07.654    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 18:28:07.654    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
04-13 18:28:07.664    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
04-13 18:28:07.664    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
04-13 18:28:07.664    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
04-13 18:28:07.664    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
04-13 18:28:07.674    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/System.err﹕ ... 25 more
04-13 18:28:07.674    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-13 18:28:07.674    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ed6438)
04-13 18:28:07.684    5453-5453/com.partytime.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.partytime.myapplication/com.partytime.myapplication.infoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.partytime.myapplication.infoActivity.onCreate(infoActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, error says:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.partytime.myapplication.infoActivity.onCreate(infoActivity.java:37)
```

So it should be related to the infoActivity

One of the possible reason is the string you passed is null and the infoActivity is getting the string and try to access the value.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,infoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("nome", title);
intent.putExtra("id", snippet);
```

If this is the reason, you can check the string in the infoActivity.

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
String title = intent.getExtra("nome");
String id = = intent.getExtra("id");

if (id == null || title == null) 
   // Exception
```

Comment: the only value im receiving in infoActivity is the id...cause, with this id i made a select to show all info for that id...and if i just remove the code to show the image on map, the app works and dont crash...if i put the code to show the icon image, the app crashes with the error

Comment: So check the id is null or not before using it.

Comment: i think dont need to check...cause it works if a remove the icon image...so the id is not null

Comment: sorry, i didnt tried to check, cause works if i remove the icon image on the map...that default google map marker (HUE_RED) works fine...only my icon imagem dont work :(

Comment: Your id is getting value from this. And it is related to the marker. Maybe that gave the null value.
          String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
           intent.putExtra("id", snippet);

Comment: how can i implementr an exception to validate id?

Comment: You can use try and catch block in the code. Also, you can use debugger in Android Studio. If not, the most basic is just use if statement to check the value is null or not just like what I wrote in the answer

Comment: i put a log on infoActivity   dao = new LocalizacoesDAO(context);
        Localizacoes loc = dao.buscarIdLocalizacoes(txtid);
        Log.d("buscarID", loc.toString());....and this is the result on logcat buscarID﹕ Localizacoes{id=75, descricao='davi', nome='davi', posicao='-40.979912750187665, -7.3828356340527534', poLatLng=lat/lng: (-40.979912750187665,-7.3828356340527534), data=26/07/2015, imagem=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-P_EPYYgeJKI/TdWnTwwTmiI/AAAAAAAABU0/Zb52GGCR-gc/s1600/Render%2B-%2BKen%2B-%2BStreet%2BFighter.png}

Comment: why doesnt work if i put  this cod to show this imagem on the icon?...something worng in this part of cod

Comment: URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(""+lista.get(i).getImagem()+"");
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    Bitmap bmpok = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 30, 30, false);                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: Yeah. But I am sure the exception is caused by the id

Comment: its not the id...im testing this app in a real device with android version 4.1.2 jellybean, and im getting this error...i tried to run this app in and genymotion emulator eith android 4.4.4 kitkat and i dont get this error...can this be a problem with the android version?